# Is there a way to get time when user joins a channel?

Tags: laravel

I am working on the app where user joins the channel. And I need to get time when user subscribes to channel. Is there a way to implement it?

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
        $ip = Request::ip();
        if (auth()->check()) { 
            return [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'ip' => $ip,
                'name' => $user->name
            ];
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not the same way you're getting the `$ip`?

```php
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
        $ip = Request::ip();
        if (auth()->check()) { 
            $time = now(); // Here
            return [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'ip' => $ip,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'joined' => $time,
            ];
        }
    });
```

[now()](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-now) helper function returns a Carbon instance with the current time

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-now)

The `now` function creates a new `Illuminate\Support\Carbon` instance for the current time:

```php
$now = now();
```